# Get href from one link and clone to another href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I'm basically trying to get the `href` from one link and then have that populate into another:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="somelinkthing.com" class="main-link">Link to thing</a>
<a class="second-link">Link to duplicate</a>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$('.main-link').attr('href', $('.second-link').attr('href'));
```

Trying to get the `href` from `.main-link` to populate to `.second-link` so it should become this:

**OUTPUT:**

```
<a href="somelinkthing.com" class="main-link">Link to thing</a>
<a href="somelinkthing.com" class="second-link">Link to duplicate</a>
```

Not sure if I have something backwards, but I am not all with it right now so that could be it too.

Comment: You just have it backwards. You're setting the href of `.main-link`, copying it from `.second-link`.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? When you call `attr()` with two arguments, it's setting, and you're doing that with `.main-link`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is setting the `href` attribute of `.main-link` rather than `.second-link` - you need to target the element you want to change:

```
$('.second-link').attr('href', $('.main-link').attr('href'));
```

Comment: So, how/where does it get the href from the main-link? Oh wait nevermind...I just saw the update, LOL!

Comment: He's not setting it to itself, he's just going the wrong way.

Comment: @tymeJV - Haha! That was a good laugh! Ok, yeah, I figured I had it backwards. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $mainLink = $('.main-link').attr('href'); 
$('.second-link').attr('href',$mainLink);
```

The first line retrieves the attribute, the second line shows how to set the attribute by following the attribute name with a comma followed by the value you wish to set the attribute to.